# actionscript variable name in another variable

Tags: actionscript-3, variables

ok, I have been trying to solve this myself for the better part of three days, with no luck. Here is a sample of code:

```
var text1:TextInput = new TextInput();
text1.text = "67"
for (var i:int = 1; i < 49;i++) {
    var test:int = int(["text" + i].text);
    trace(test);
}
```

this should output "67" but it only outputs "0". I have tried several combinations of bracket placement, with no luck.  If I change the line:

```
    var test:int = int(["text" + i].text);
```

to this:

```
    var test:int = int(["text" + i] + ".text");
```

when i check the value in the debugger, it shows me that ["text" + i] + ".text" yields "text1.text", but not the string "67". any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Wes

Comment: You did almost right but you need to use `this` before square brackets where you put your computed string. Once you do, it'll work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

And what about using `this` keyword:

```
for (var i:int = 1; i < 49;i++) {
    var field:TextInput = this["text" + i];
    var test:int = int( field ? field.text : 0);
    trace(test);
}
```